# Passing optional props through a spread 'props'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've got some nested components (so that there is a separation of concern) that pass optional components through:

```js
const FooBarMenu = ({ match }) => {
  return <div>
    {isFooBarLoadable ? (
      <FooBarLoader action={action} label='Foo Bar' selector={getLoadedFooBar}>
        <FooBar />
      </FooBarLoader>
    ) : <FooBarPlaceholder />}
  };
```

then the `<FooBarLoader>` looks like:

```js
type FooBarLoaderProps = {
  action: Function,
  children?: React.ReactNode,
  selector: (state: MyProjectState) => MightError<string>,
  props: {} // <-- this worked, but is where issues start
}

const FooBarLoader = ({
  action,
  children = undefined,
  selector,
  ...props
}: FooBarLoaderProps) => {

// do stuff to load FooBars (or not)

const error = useSelector(compose(getErrorFromState, selector));
// etc...

return (
  <LoadingSpinner
    error={error}
    {...props}
  >
    {children}
  </LoadingSpinner>
)

}
```

and our `LoadingSpinner` looks like:

```js
type LoadingSpinnerProps = {
  children?: React.ReactNode,
  error?: string,
  label?: string,
  // etc... many more optional props
};

const LoadingSpinner = ({
  children = undefined,
  error = undefined,
  label = '...',
  // etc... many more props with defaults
}: LoadingSpinnerProps) => {
  // figure out if we needs to show an error etc
  // show label
  // Show spinning progress
};
```

the issue is now I'm converting the javascript component FooBarMenu to use typescript, I'm seeing an issue where `FooBarLoader` is expecting `label` as part of the `props`, but that doesn't work with how the types are being declared?

I'm seeing 'property label does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FooBarLoaderProps'. Trying to use `props: Partial<{ label: string }>` in `FooBarLoaderProps` still shouts that it doesn't know what label is.

If I have :

```js
type FooBarLoaderProps = {
  action: Function,
  children?: React.ReactNode,
  selector: (state: MyProjectState) => MightError<string>,
  label?: string,
  props: {},
}
```

And I provide `label` it complains I don't have a `props` prop (even though before it seemed fine?). Instead I need to mark both as optional, which seems like it's missing the point that `label` is part of props.

How should I be declaring the `FooBarLoaderProps` type, to include the optional props in `props`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't get the second error, because the first one was preventing it.

You declare `props`, but you don't use it. `...props` in the component is not the same as `props` in your types. You can name the first one as you want.

Your type should look like this:

```
type FooBarLoaderProps = {
  action: Function,
  children?: React.ReactNode,
  selector: (state: MyProjectState) => MightError<string>,
  label?: string,
  // list other props here
}
```

or

```
type FooBarLoaderProps = {
  action: Function,
  children?: React.ReactNode,
  selector: (state: MyProjectState) => MightError<string>,
  label?: string,
} & LoadingSpinnerProps
```

Comment: It looks like this works and it makes sense to me. I had to `Omit` some stuff that I hadn't put in my original example, but it's all good now. Thanks!